# Why my Picturebox with labels is moved when saving

Tags: c#, visual-studio, bitmap, label, picturebox

I have a big problem when I convert my PictureBox to bitmap with labels to save it in my computer, it appears moved and with a really low resolution, I'm a newbie so... I really don't know how to fix it

[here is how it looks saved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIQTo.jpg)

here is my code to save it:

```
System.Drawing.Point pbloc = pictureBox1.PointToScreen(pictureBox1.Location);
        Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Size.Width, pictureBox1.Size.Height);
        Graphics grx = Graphics.FromImage(bm);
        grx.CopyFromScreen(pbloc.X, pbloc.Y, 0, 0, pictureBox1.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
        grx.Dispose();


        SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
        sfd.Filter = "JPG(*.JPG)|*.jpg";
        if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            bm.Save(sfd.FileName,
        System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        }
```

I used this to parent the labels with the PictureBox:

```
public Registro()
    {

        InitializeComponent();


        var pos1 = this.PointToScreen(label1.Location);
        pos1 = pictureBox1.PointToClient(pos1);
        this.label1.Parent = this.pictureBox1;
        label1.Location = pos1;
```

Comment: Moving: Why didn't youi use DrawToBitmap? - Resolution: You will always only get the screen resolution.

Comment: Awesome!, Thanks!, DrawToBitmap worked, but, there is any way to save it in original resolution? (it was +3000px), or just in a better one?, i need it for a Letter Paper Size, to print

Comment: because my laptop resolution i can't do a bigger image

Comment: The by far best results will be drawing the image and the texts into a bitmap of the size and dpi you choose. Use DrawImage and DrawString.